# How to think about random CDF?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

[Chi (2014, "The Value of Information and Dispersion")](http://dev.gtcenter.org/Downloads/Conf/Chi1844.pdf) defines a RV $X^*$ by the continuous distribution of (footnote 7, pg. 6):

$$ G(x) = \begin{cases} (1-p) U_1 & \mbox{if } x=0 \\ 1-p & \mbox{if } x \in (0,1)\\ 1-p + p U_2 & \mbox{if } x = 1\end{cases}$$

where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are i.i.d. RVs, distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$.

He claims that $X^*$ is statistically equivalent to a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p$.

How to think about $G(x)$? If $G(x)$ is not the CDF which describes $X^*$, what is $X^*$'s CDF? Is $g(x) = 0\ \forall x$? In order to compute an expected value, would I implicitly simply plug in expected values for $U_1$ and $U_2$?

Comment: Your question is unclear, because this formula does not describe a CDF except in the case $U_2=1$, which has zero chance of occurring.  You (or Chi) appear to have confused a CDF with a random variable.  To avoid this problem it would be a good idea to transcribe the footnote *exactly*.

Comment: Thank you.  I am still puzzling over what Chi might mean by "statistically equivalent."  Does he define that anywhere in the paper?

Comment: No, can't find any definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chi's notation makes little sense.  Fortunately, this construction comes from a 1988 paper of E. L. Lehmann, [Comparing Location Experiments](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4614-1412-4_61.pdf), where it is more clearly (if very briefly) described.

The concepts are interesting.  I will describe Lehmann's idea of equivalent experiments, then illustrate and explain his construction.

---

#### "Statistical equivalence"

Lehmann begins with the idea of *equivalent experiments.*  His language is so pithy and clear that I shall just quote some of the definitions.

> An experiment $\mathbf{E}$ is a random quantity $X$ and a family $\mathbf{P} = \{P_\theta,\,\theta\in\Omega\}$ of possible distributions of $X$.  Let $\mathbf{F} = (Y,\,\mathbf{Q}=\{Q_\theta, \theta\in\Omega\})$ be another experiment, with the distributions $P_\theta$ and $Q_\theta$ corresponding to the same state of nature $\theta$.

Lehmann gives four nearly equivalent characterizations of what it means for an experiment $\mathbf{F}$ to be *more informative* than an experiment $\mathbf{E}$.  The importance of the idea is made plain by the second characterization:

> For any decision procedure $\delta$ based on $X$ and any loss function $L(\theta,d)$ there exists a (possibly randomized) procedure $\delta^\prime$ based on $Y$ such that $R(\theta,\delta^\prime) = R(\theta,\delta)$ for all $\theta$.

(Lehmann assumes his readers will know that $R$ is the *risk function* for a state of nature $\theta$ using decision $d$: by definition, it is the expected loss of $d$.)  Thus, we are never any worse off basing decisions on $Y$ instead of $X$ (and might, for some states of nature, actually be better off) in the sense of expected loss.

Two experiments are *equivalent* when each is more informative than the other.  I believe this is what Chi intended "statistically equivalent" to mean.

#### Constructing $X^{*}$ from $X$

> Suppose $X$ has a discontinuity at $x_0$, with $\Pr(X=x_0)=p$ when $\theta=\theta_0$.  Define a new variable $X^{*}$ by $$\eqalign{X^{*}&= X, &\quad\text{if }X\lt x_0, \\ &= X + pU, &\quad\text{if }X = x_0, \\ &=X + p, &\quad\text{if }X \gt x_0,}$$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

[At pp 785-786.]

Let's work out the distribution of $X^{*}$ in terms of the distribution $F_X$ of $X$.  To do so, notice $X$ is determined uniquely--without any randomness--in terms of $X^{*}$:

$$\eqalign{
X &= X^{*},   &\quad\text{if } X^{*} \lt x_0 \\
  &= x_0,     &\quad\text{if } x_0 \le X^{*} \lt x_0 + p \\
  &= X^{*}-p, &\quad\text{if } X^{*} \ge x_0 + p.
}$$

[image: Figure: graph of the inverse]

The graph of $X$ *versus* $X^{*}$ shows that $X$ is a continuous function of $X^{*}$, but it is not one-to-one.  A total probability of $p$ is assigned to the interval from $x_0$ to $x_0+p$ for $X^{*}$.  This causes the cumulative probability of $X$ to jump by $p$ at $X=x_0$, exactly as desired.

We can work out what this transformation does to the distribution $F_X$ to create the distribution $F_{X^{*}}$.  They are the same for $x \lt x_0$.  For $x_0 \le x^{*} \lt x_0+p$, $F_{X^{*}}$ increases with unit slope to cover the vertical jump of $p$ in $F_X$ at $x_0$.  Thenceforth they agree once more, with $F_{X^{*}}(x^{*}) = F_X(x^{*}-p)$ when $x^{*} \ge x_0+p$.

[image: Figure showing the transformation of the CDFs]

Geometrically, the graph on the left is sliced vertically at $x=x_0$ and then pulled apart sideways by a distance $p$.  That jump, shown with a dotted gray line, now stretches across at a unit slope, also shown with a dotted gray line at right.  Consequently, *$X^{*}$ has no jump at $x_0$*.

By repeating this construction at each discrete jump of $X$ we eventually obtain a variable $X^{*}$ with no jumps: it is continuous.  This is what Chi was trying to describe.

#### What the construction accomplishes

We saw earlier how the value of $X^{*}$ determines the value of $X$.  Conversely, the value of $X$ usually determines one value of $X^{*}$, but wherever $X$ has a jump it is associated only with an interval of values of $X^{*}$ (and the specific value in that interval is determined by the random variable $U$).  Thus, *$X^{*}$ is more informative than $X$.*  However, since the additional information in $X^{*}$ tells us only about the values of $U$, *which is independent of $X$*, $X^{*}$ is no more informative than $X$: $X$ and $X^{*}$ are equivalent in Lehmann's sense.

The purpose of this construction is to avoid having to reason separately about discrete distributions.  By applying this construction beforehand, all analysis may focus on *continuous* variables.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent and extremely insightful explanation!